# android getView not calling in base adapter

Tags: android, android-listview

I've used this code for more then 6 month but it's been a couple of hours that it't not calling getview , I don't know why . I logged the adapter size and it has 1 item but getView is not calling .

I also logged the adapter size in getCount() and it has 1 item . this is the code :

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity activity;
    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

    public ListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
        super();
        this.activity = (Activity) activity;
        this.list = list;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();

    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
        if (this.list == null) {
            this.list = result;
        } else {
            this.list.addAll(result);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> geting(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView img;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("this","comes");
        ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        if (convertView == null) {
            if(isTablet)
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_ekhtesasi_grid, null);
            else
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_ekhtesasi, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        item = list.get(position);
        Log.v("this",item.get("img"));


        return convertView;
    }

    public void clear() {
        if (this.list.size() > 0)
            this.list.clear();
    }
}
```

as you can see, i've put a log on the first line of getview , but it doesn't get in .

Could you help me ? why is that ?

Comment: try returning `arg0` in `getItemId()`

Comment: you have to change your log and put the position value Log.v("this",item.get(position));

Comment: @Nilesh thanks for answer but not working

Comment: @br00 thanks for answer but the problem is the log on the first line of getView is not calling at all

Comment: Where are override annotations?

Comment: can you post some code of your listview?Where and how you create listview?

Comment: @degrigorash  I tried .not working

Comment: are you associating the listview with the adapter? this just a common mistake which I usually do..

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about @Override.
Mark this methods as @Override and it will work fine:
public int getCount() 
public Object getItem(int position)
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Activity activity;
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;

public ListAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list) {
    super();
    this.activity = (Activity) activity;
    this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

public void addAll(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    if (this.list == null) {
        this.list = result;
    } else {
        this.list.addAll(result);
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public HashMap<String, String> geting(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView img;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.v("this","comes");
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    if (convertView == null) {
        if(isTablet)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_ekhtesasi_grid, null);
        else
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ads_ekhtesasi, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.img = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    item = list.get(position);
    Log.v("this",item.get("img"));


    return convertView;
}

public void clear() {
    if (this.list.size() > 0)
        this.list.clear();
}
```

}

Comment: This won't help.  The `@Override` annotation won't magically make it work. It isn't necessary to mark overridden methods with `@Override` and they will still override methods as long as they are correctly named and have the correct argument profile. Using the `@Override` annotation is generally a good idea as it allows the compiler to warn you when you're not overriding something when you think you are (e.g. because you made a typo in the method name or specified the wrong arguments).